# In android, when changing the orientation, text in textview is not getting wrapped

Tags: android, android-custom-view, textview

im locking the screen orientation by specifying ***android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"***

im setting a text to a textview and adding it to a custom viewgroup. when changing the orientation im changing the width and height of the textview.

when Im running the application, if I have the screen in landscape, the text is in single line and if in portrait, the text is in two lines. so there is enough space to display the text in both orientations.

But when I change the orientation from Landscape to portrait, the text is not wrapping and I can see only a part. If I change the orientation from portrait to landscape, the text was getting displayed in two lines and not getting stretched.

Whether I want to do anything in **onConfigurationChanged() Method**????

Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: have you checked out your layout xml file? you should check the layout_height and layout_width of that EditText view, the problem may be residing there..

Comment: its a labelview im creating it dynamically...

Comment: if I clear all the views and set the textview again in onconfigurationchanged() method, textview is properly wrapping the text in the given space. any idea why its happening? how to solve it?